# UITextView content inset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

I have encountered something a bit strange with contentInsets

I have a UITextView in my storyboard with a contentInset of 50 left, as I'm trying to add some padding to my uitextview

However, a scrollbar appears on the bottom of the uitextview, as shown below in this test:[image]

I was under the impression that contentInset squashes the uitextview without causing this horizontal scroll bar, so how can I remove the need for the horizontal scrollbar and make everything--the inset AND all the text in the uitextview--visible without the need for this scrollbar.

N.B: I'm not asking about preventing the scrolling horizontally or not displaying the scrollbar(thus cutting of the text)

Thanks a lot!

For atomk(UITextView is called ss)

```
NSLog(@"Content Size Before %f",self.ss.contentSize.width); Logs: 280
CGSize size=self.ss.contentSize; size.width=size.width-50;
[self.ss setContentSize:size]; 
NSLog(@"Content Size After %f",self.ss.contentSize.width); Logs: 230
```

There is **no** visible difference between the view with the code added than before it was added, so something's going wrong!
(Thanks)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**UPDATE: This solution is out of date as of iOS 7.**

See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20052756/1367622). In iOS 7.0, the [`textContainerInset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/textContainerInset) property on `UITextView` was introduced.

Objective-C:

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 0);
```

Swift:

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Or as [Zeev Vax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560412/uitextview-content-inset/18604414#comment110812177_20052756) suggested, in Swift 5.0:

```
textView.textContainerInset.left = 50
```

---

**Pre-iOS 7 solution:**

> I was under the impression that contentInset squashes the uitextview without causing this horizontal scroll bar...

I'm afraid this is not how `contentInset` works with a `UITextView`. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset) for `contentInset` where it states:

> The distance that the content view is inset from the enclosing scroll view... Use this property to add to the scrolling area around the content.

The `contentInset` is *added* around the content.

---

You can change the `contentSize` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` using the code you have included above:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 50, 0, 0);
    
    NSLog(@"Content Size Before %f",self.textView.contentSize.width); //Logs: 280
    CGSize size=self.textView.contentSize;
    size.width=size.width-50;
    [self.textView setContentSize:size];
    NSLog(@"Content Size After %f",self.textView.contentSize.width); //Logs: 230
}
```

However, this causes the text to be cut off on the right side:

[image: UITextView cut off on right side]

---

The best way I have been able to achieve the appearance of horizontal padding in a `UITextView` is to position it inside a container `UIView`. In your case, simply create a `UIView` the same size as your current text view, and add a text view that is 50px narrower inside the container view.

This workaround can cause problems if you have a background for your text view, but from your screenshot above it doesn't look like that's an issue for you.

`UITextView` (frame in red) inside `UIView` container:

[image: UITextView inside container UIView]

If your `UITextView` does have a background, see:

- [How to set UITextView's content inset like Notes App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931431/how-to-set-uitextviews-content-inset-like-notes-app)
- [Stuff you learn from reverse-engineering Notes.app](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/stuff-you-learn-from-reverse-engineering-notes-app/) (see "iPadding" section)

Answer (score 203):

In iOS 7 `UITextView` is based on TextKit and has a new property `textContainerInset`. It behaves just as you would expect:

```
UITextView *textView = ...;
// Left inset of 50 points
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: One suggestion, the inset struct properties are var now (swift 5.0) you can do :
textView.textContainerInset.left = 50